# Python descriptor returning itself not value when called from class

Tags: python, descriptor

I want to make an attribute accessible from instance and class that cannot be reassigned. I have the "prevent from reassigned" part tackled thanks to a metaclass. However, now the attribute cannot be read from the class. How to make it so.

Having this:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __setattr__(cls, attr, val):
        if attr =="frozen":
            print "You can't unfreeze the frozen"
        else:
            cls.name = val


class Fixed(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    frzn = 'I AM AWESOME'
    def holdset(_,val):
        _.frzn = _.frzn
        print "frozen is frozen not setting to ", val

    def get(_):
        return _.frzn
    frozen = property(fset=holdset,fget=get)
```

When calling

```
print Fixed.frozen
print Fixed().frozen
```

Gives

```
<property object at 0x106dbeba8>
I AM AWESOME
```

Why doesn't it give the same? How to make it give the same?

Comment: Why would you call the first parameter `_` rather than `self`, which is the universal Python convention?

Comment: How about you shrink that code by removing the metaclass, and test whether the issue remains. If so, ta-dah! you can simplify your question, or perhaps even find a solution yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `property` normally only works on an instance. To make a property work on a class too, you'll need to create your own descriptor instead:

```
class ClassAndInstanceProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.fdel = fdel
        if doc is None and fget is not None:
            doc = fget.__doc__
        self.__doc__ = doc

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            obj = objtype
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        self.fset(obj, value)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        if self.fdel is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
        self.fdel(obj)

    def getter(self, fget):
        return type(self)(fget, self.fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def setter(self, fset):
        return type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def deleter(self, fdel):
        return type(self)(self.fget, self.fset, fdel, self.__doc__)
```

The only difference between the above and a regular `property` is in the `__get__` method; a normal `property` object does (in C) the equivalent of:

```
def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
    if obj is None:
        return self
    if self.fget is None:
        raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
    return self.fget(obj)
```

e.g. on a class the descriptor returns `self`, while my version sets `obj` to `objtype` in that case.

Also note that a descriptor `__set__` method is *only* called when working with an instance; `Fixed.frozen = 'something'` would not invoke the descriptor `__set__`, only `Fixed().frozen = 'something'` would. Your metaclass `__setattr__` intercepts the attribute assignment on the class instead.

You could also put a descriptor object on the *metaclass*, which would then be given the opportunity to have it's `__set__` called for attribute assignment on the class itself.

Comment: "You could also put a descriptor object on the class, which would then be given the opportunity to have it's __set__ called for attribute assignment on the class itself." How could this be achieved? Could it be achieved by putting the descriptor on the metaclass?

Answer (score 1):

By convention a Python descriptor returns itself when not called with an instance.  Properties are just a shortcut for a descriptor, to do this you need to implement your own descriptor. The following should do what you want, without needing a metaclass:

```
class Frozen(object):
    def __init__(self, fixed_value):
        self.fixed_value = fixed_value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        return self.fixed_value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print "You can't unfreeze the frozen"


class Fixed(object):
    frzn = Frozen("I AM AWESOME")
```

You would also probably want to override the **delete** method which is part of the descriptor interface.  There are some good articles explaining exactly how descriptors work.

Comment: `Fixed.frzn = 'spam'` will *not* invoke the descriptor `__set__` method though. You'd need to have a descriptor on the metaclass instead for that to work.

Comment: @Martijn.  Good point -- a metaclass would be necessary to prevent Fixed.frzn from overriding the class property.  I'm not sure that's what the OP wants to do though.

Comment: Perhaps that's why the OP is using a metaclass with `__setattr__`?

Comment: Quite possibly.  It's not clear whether there's an intent to prevent setting the property via class object, or just a desire to have Fixed.frzn and Fixed().frzn return the same thing while prevening Fixes().frzn = 'something."  A metaclass may or not be overkill depending on what this is being used for.